# using enter method to deal with variables in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am working on data for logistic regression 
I used enter method to deal with variables
Is it enough or i have to use forward and backward?
Is there any references or reports supporting using enter method alone?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should *not* use forward and backward. Using the enter method alone is enough if you have strong hypotheses about which variables belong in the model. Some will say that you should drop variables that are not significant but I disagree.

1. If you have a strong hypothesis that a variable should be related to the dependent variable, then finding that it is *not* is important.
2. Effect sizes are what's interesting
3. A variable may be important as a control variable
4. By doing exactly what you set out to do (test one hypothesis) you remove some potential problems.

Answer (score -2):

Just try different methods and validate which is the best model for your purposes. Depending on the dataset you'll get different solutions or not using one method or another one. You have to "avoid" the collineality and be sure that your independent variables aren't correlated.